# Best/Faster? way to reverse many to many relationship list in R

Tags: r, list, dictionary

What is the best/better way than below, i.e. faster way to reverse many to many relationship in R.  This example is not important but the time is takes to do it of a list this size, initial list ~ 36,000 values and reverse list is ~ 11,500 values.  Is this possible to vectorize or use mapply?

```
library(hgu95av2.db)

xx <- as.list(hgu95av2ALIAS2PROBE)

## aliases that have probes
alias_values <- xx[!is.na(xx)]

## reverse the many to many relationship
probe_to_alias = list()
for (alias in names(alias_values)) {
  for (probe_id in alias_values[[alias]]) {
    if (!(probe_id %in% names(probe_to_alias))) {
      probe_to_alias[[probe_id]] <- c(alias)
    } else {
      probe_to_alias[[probe_id]] <- append(probe_to_alias[[probe_id]], alias)
    }
  }
}
probe_to_alias[1:2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one improvement:

```r
library(hgu95av2.db)

xx <- as.list(hgu95av2ALIAS2PROBE)

## aliases that have probes
alias_values <- xx[!is.na(xx)]

## reverse the many to many relationship
probe_to_alias = list()
for (alias in names(alias_values)) {
  for (probe_id in alias_values[[alias]]) {
    probe_to_alias[[probe_id]] <- append(probe_to_alias[[probe_id]], alias)
  }
}
```

The difference is it doesn't check if the probe already has an entry. That check was taking up a good chunk of time, especially as the list got longer.

I also experimented with a bunch of different options using lapply, but couldn't find anything faster.

Comment: ok great.  I thought you have to initialize an entry.